# java.io.IOException: Pipe closed appears when using pipeWriter and pipeReader

Tags: java, multithreading, pipeline

I'm trying to implement a program that explains the Pipe&Line data flow architecture.
I have a Data Source and many filters ,the Data Source class writes on the pipe an array of characters (using PipeWriter), and the first filter reads the array from the pipe and converts the characters into upperCase and then writes the array of upperCase characters into the same Pipe in order to be read by the next filter and so on.
I'm using multithreading in my application.
here is some code that might explain what i'm trying to do:

```
public class DataSource implements Runnable{
   PipedWriter pw;
   public char[] c  = {'e','a','b','c','e','c','a','f','e','d'};
   public DataSource(PipedWriter pw){
        this.pw = pw;
   }

public  synchronized  void run() {
    try {
        pw.write(c);
        pw.write(-1);
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataSource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
 }
```

---

```
public class UpperCaseConversionFilter implements Runnable{
PipedReader pr;
PipedWriter pw;
char[] upperCaseLetters;

public UpperCaseConversionFilter(PipedReader pr,PipedWriter pw){
    this.pr = pr;
    this.pw = pw;
    upperCaseLetters = new char[10];
}
public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        int i;
        int d = 0 ;
        while ((i = pr.read()) != -1) {
           char y = (char)i;
           upperCaseLetters[d] = Character.toUpperCase(y);
           d++;
       }
           pw.write(upperCaseLetters);   // here apperas the exception
           pw.write(-1);
           pw.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UpperCaseConversionFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

and  here is how I test the code:

```
 public static  void facadDetails(){
    PipedWriter pw = null;
    PipedReader pr = null;
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        pr = new PipedReader();
        pw = new PipedWriter(pr);
        DataSource dso = new DataSource(pw);
        UpperCaseConversionFilter f1 = new UpperCaseConversionFilter(pr,pw);

        new Thread(dso).start();
        new Thread(f1).start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }



     }
```

Can any one help me solve this ?!!

Comment: I really need help !! I don't know what's the problem and its the first time I deal with PipeReader and Writer :(:(

Answer (score 0):

"and then writes the array of upperCase characters into the same Pipe in order to be read by the next filter" - this is wrong. If you write to the same pipe, it is read by itself (making infinite loop), not the next filter.

I guess you wanted something like:

DataSource => pw1->pr1 => UpperCaseConversionFilter => pw2->pr2 => next filter

So you need 2 or more pairs of (PipedWriter, PipedReader).